# Python - Pyqt: Duplicate output when I use setCurrentIndex

Tags: python, pyqt, duplicates

When I press the button for go to a diferent page using setCurrentIndex I have problems with duplicate output values because if I set value "1" on QLineEdit on home_page for example and then go to conf_page and now I back to home_page, when I press the OK button for print content of QLineEdit for example, I get a duplicate output.

My code.

Project.py file.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(210, 191)
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 211, 61))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.stackedWidget = QtGui.QStackedWidget(Dialog)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 211, 131))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stackedWidget"))
        self.page = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.page)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 90, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page_2"))
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None))
```

Project.pyw file.

```
from project import *
import sys

class project(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.home_page)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.down_page)

    def home_page(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.output)

    def down_page(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def output(self):
        print(self.ui.lineEdit.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = project()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any sugestions?
Thanks!!

Comment: I don't see anything and obviously it's because your project is a lot larger, but without a minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible code snippet, it will be hard to debug. You could try PDB or a printing stack traces to see how the function calls occur prior to the bug.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I posted a test project so you can see what happens to me. If I press the pushButton_3, then press pushButton_2 and then pusshButton_2 the output of home_page is duplicated 2 times. If I change more times of page the output increases.

Comment: put QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.output) inside __init__

Comment: Hi Achayan. Thanks for response, it's works!